# crypt function and link error "undefined reference to 'crypt'"

Tags: c, linker-errors, crypt

I have used the crypt function in c to encrypt the given string.
I have written the following code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n",crypt("passwd",1000));
}
```

But the above code threw an error ,"undefined reference to `crypt'".
What is the problem in the above code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Didn't `crypt` do hashing instead of encryption?

Comment: @Joha: no, otherwise it would be called `hash` wouldn't it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to use the `crypt()` function, you need to link to the library that supplies it.  Add `-lcrypt` to your compile command.

Older versions of glibc supplied a `libcrypt` library for this purpose, and declared the function in `<unistd.h>` - to compile against this support, you may also need to define either `_XOPEN_SOURCE` or `_GNU_SOURCE` in your code before including `<unistd.h>`.

Newer versions of glibc don't supply `libcrypt` - it is instead provided by a separate `libxcrypt`.  You still link with `-lcrypt`, but the function is instead declared in `<crypt.h>`.

Answer (score 7):

`crypt()` uses DES which is **extremely insecure** and <s>probably older than you</s> 12 years older than you.

I suggest you use a serious encryption algorithm, such as AES. Many libraries offer such encryption; [OpenSSL (crypto.lib)](http://www.openssl.org/) is a good choice for example.

<sup>Not answering your actual question since a lot of people already did</sup>

Comment: "The GNU C Library used by almost all Linux distributions provides an implementation of the crypt function which supports the DES, MD5, and SHA based hashing algorithms" (according to Wikipedia at least)

Answer (score 2):

You have to `#define __XOPEN_SOURCE` before you `#include` the header files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include crypt.h if you want to use `crypt()`. Below your other two includes, add:

```
#include <crypt.h>
```

Comment: I have added this line into my code.After that also it is throwing same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the following line before your includes:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
```

Answer (score 0):

The `crypt` function is non-standard, but is supplied as an extension by the GNU C library on Linux. It's defined in `<crypt.h>`