# undefined reference to `crypt'

Tags: c, cryptography, linker-errors, crypt

I am using the below code that i found somewhere in the net and i am getting an error when i try to build it. The compilation is ok.

Here is the error:

```
/tmp/ccCnp11F.o: In function `main':

crypt.c:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `crypt'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <crypt.h>

 int main()
 {
   unsigned long seed[2];
   char salt[] = "$1$........";
   const char *const seedchars =
     "./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST"
     "UVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   char *password;
   int i;

   /* Generate a (not very) random seed.
      You should do it better than this... */
   seed[0] = time(NULL);
   seed[1] = getpid() ^ (seed[0] >> 14 & 0x30000);

   /* Turn it into printable characters from `seedchars'. */
   for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
     salt[3+i] = seedchars[(seed[i/5] >> (i%5)*6) & 0x3f];

   /* Read in the user's password and encrypt it. */
   password = crypt(getpass("Password:"), salt);

   /* Print the results. */
   puts(password);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [crypt function and link error "undefined reference to 'crypt'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565427/crypt-function-and-link-error-undefined-reference-to-crypt)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`crypt.c:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to 'crypt'` is a linker error.

Try linking with `-lcrypt` : `gcc crypt.c -lcrypt`.

Answer (score 2):

You've to add -lcrypt when compiling... Imagine the source file is called crypttest.c, you'll do:

```
cc -lcrypt -o crypttest crypttest.c
```

Answer (score -1):

Chances are you forget to link the library

```
  gcc ..... -lcrypt
```

Answer (score -1):

This could be due to two reasons:

1. Linking with the crypt library: use `-l<nameOfCryptLib>` as a flag to `gcc`.
   Example: `gcc ... -lcrypt` where `crypt.h` has been compiled into a library.
2. The file `crypt.h` is not in the `include path`. You can use `<` and `>` tags around a header file only when the file is in the `include path`. To ensure that `crypt.h` is present in the include path, use the `-I` flag, like so: `gcc ... -I<path to directory containing crypt.h> ...`
   Example: `gcc -I./crypt`  where `crypt.h` is present in the `crypt/ sub-directory` of the current directory.

If you do not want to use the `-I` flag, change the `#include<crypt.h>` to `#include "crypt.h"`