# Error cross compiling OpenSSH (Embedded Linux)

Tags: c, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, openssh

Followed many tutorials so far and had various error. Below is the complete step by step procedure that i followed and ended up having errors with OpenSSH compilation.

**Downloaded Zlib and cross compiled ($HOME/Desktop/Zlib/zlib-1.2.5/output)**

```
cd /home/armsdk/Desktop/
mkdir zlib
cd Zlib
wget http://www.zlib.net/fossils/zlib-1.2.5.tar.gz
tar xzvf zlib-1.2.5.tar.gz
cd zlib-1.2.5
mkdir output
./configure --prefix=/home/armsdk/Desktop/Zlib/zlib-1.2.5/output CC=arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi-gcc 
make
make install
```

**Downloaded OpenSSL and cross compiled : ($HOME/Desktop/OpenSSL/OpenSSL_CC)**

```
mkdir OpenSSL
cd OpenSSL
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz
tar xzvf openssl-1.0.1g.tar.gz      
cd openssl-1.0.1g/
export cross=arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi-
./Configure dist --prefix=$HOME/Desktop/OpenSSL/OpenSSL_CC
make CC="${cross}gcc" AR="${cross}ar r" RANLIB="${cross}ranlib"
make install
```

**Cross Compiled OpenSSH :**

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/Desktop/OpenSSH/OpenSSH_CC --host=arm --with-libs --with-zlib=$HOME/Desktop/Zlib/zlib-1.2.5/output --with-ssl-dir=$HOME/Desktop/OpenSSL/OpenSSL_CC --disable-etc-default-login CC=arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR=arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi-ar
make
```

**GETTING CRYPT ERROR:**

```
openbsd-compat//libopenbsd-compat.a(xcrypt.o): In function `xcrypt':
/home/armsdk/Desktop/OpenSSH/openssh-5.2p1/openbsd-compat/xcrypt.c:78: undefined reference to `crypt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help me resolve. All i need is SFTP-Server for remote debugging using gdbServer (via Eclipse)

---

**Compiling on system running** : Debian Wheezy

**Target Board** : Ka-Ro TX6S

**Target Processor** : NXP i.MX6S7

**Host Linux version** : 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64

**Target Linux Version** : 4.4.0-00118-g26d6b51

**CrossCompiler** : gcc-arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi

---

**Update 1:**

Adding the below line Gave error:

```
-I/home/armsdk/Desktop/OpenSSL/OpenSSL_CC/include
```

**Error**

```
 configure: error: unrecognized option: -I/home/armsdk/Desktop/OpenSSL/OpenSSL_CC/include
```

Tried this instead but the CRYPT error still exists.

```
--includedir=/home/armsdk/Desktop/OpenSSL/OpenSSL_CC/include
```

---

**Update 2:**

Tried -lcrypt flag as suggested here : [undefined reference to `crypt'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989444/undefined-reference-to-crypt) But this doesnt have any change in error.

```
make clean
make -lcrypt
```

---

**Update 3:**
Added 'CFLAGS=-lcrypt' and the error now changed

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/Desktop/OpenSSH/OpenSSH_CC --host=arm --with-libs --with-zlib=$HOME/Desktop/Zlib/zlib-1.2.5/output --with-ssl-dir=$HOME/Desktop/OpenSSL/OpenSSL_CC --disable-etc-default-login CC=arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR=arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi-ar CFLAGS=-lcrypt
```

**Error**

```
openbsd-compat//libopenbsd-compat.a(xcrypt.o): In function `xcrypt':
xcrypt.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `crypt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sshd] Error 1
```

---

**Update 4:**
Updated the LDFLAGS and CFLAGS as below:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/Desktop/OpenSSH/OpenSSH_CC --host=arm --with-libs --with-zlib=$HOME/Desktop/Zlib/zlib-1.2.5/output --with-ssl-dir=$HOME/Desktop/OpenSSL/OpenSSL_CC --disable-etc-default-login CC=arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR=arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi-ar LDFLAGS=-L/home/cross-gcc-4.9.1-2.19-18-armv7a-soft/x86_64-pc-linux-gn‌​‌​u/arm-cortexa9-lin‌​ux‌​-gnueabi/sys-roo‌​t/li‌​b CFLAGS=-lcrypt
```

Issue is still the same:

```
openbsd-compat//libopenbsd-compat.a(xcrypt.o): In function `xcrypt':
xcrypt.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `crypt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sshd] Error 1
```

---

**Update 5:**

I finally got it to successfully 'MAKE'but not able to 'make install'

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/Desktop/OpenSSH/OpenSSH_CC --host=arm --with-libs --with-zlib=$HOME/Desktop/Zlib/zlib-1.2.5/output --with-ssl-dir=$HOME/Desktop/OpenSSL/OpenSSL_CC --disable-etc-default-login CC=arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR=arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi-ar LDFLAGS='-L/home/cross-gcc-4.9.1-2.19-18-armv7a-soft/x86_64-pc-linux-gn‌​‌​u/arm-cortexa9-lin‌​ux‌​-gnueabi/sys-roo‌​t/li‌​b -lcrypt'

make    
make install
```

Error when 'make install'

```
(umask 022 ; ./mkinstalldirs /var/empty)
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh /home/armsdk/Desktop/OpenSSH/OpenSSH_CC/bin/ssh
strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/home/armsdk/Desktop/OpenSSH/OpenSSH_CC/bin/ssh'
/usr/bin/install: strip process terminated
```

---

**Update 6 : Hopefully Final**

So i finally am able to generate the outputs by adding the flag '--disable-strip'

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/Desktop/OpenSSH/OpenSSH_CC --host=arm --disable-strip --with-libs --with-zlib=$HOME/Desktop/Zlib/zlib-1.2.5/output --with-ssl-dir=$HOME/Desktop/OpenSSL/OpenSSL_CC --disable-etc-default-login CC=arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR=arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi-ar LDFLAGS='-L/home/cross-gcc-4.9.1-2.19-18-armv7a-soft/x86_64-pc-linux-gn‌​‌​u/arm-cortexa9-lin‌​ux‌​-gnueabi/sys-roo‌​t/li‌​b -lcrypt'
make
make install
```

**One small issue though, i had this error :**

```
mkdir /home/armsdk/Desktop/OpenSSH/OpenSSH_CC/etc
./ssh-keygen: 1: ./ssh-keygen: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
./ssh-keygen: 1: ./ssh-keygen: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
./ssh-keygen: 1: ./ssh-keygen: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
make: *** [host-key] Error 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined reference to \`crypt'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989444/undefined-reference-to-crypt)

Comment: After adding the -lcrypt flag to the Compiler Flags, the error now matches with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989444/undefined-reference-to-crypt

Have no idea what to do now, the above thread's solution was to add the -lcrypt flag.

Comment: Do you have the libcrypt library for arm in your system? Mine is under /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/ as well as under x86 folders

Comment: @k_kaz hi, I can find 'libcrypt-2.19.so' and 'libcrypt.so.1' in this path : /home/cross-gcc-4.9.1-2.19-18-armv7a-soft/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi/sys-root/lib/

Comment: @FerozeMohamed So please use `-L /home/cross-gcc-4.9.1-2.19-18-armv7a-soft/x86_64-pc-linux-gn‌​u/arm-cortexa9-linux‌​-gnueabi/sys-root/li‌​b/ -lcrypt`.

Comment: Should not it be `LDFLAGS`?

Comment: @Jakuje did the same and updated the OP with Update 4, still same error. I am obviously missing something here.

Comment: I don't see `-lcrypt` in `LDFLAGS` in your example

Comment: @Jakuje I added 'LDFLAGS=-L/home/cross-gcc-4.9.1-2.19-18-armv7a-soft/x86_64-pc-linux-gn‌​‌​u/arm-cortexa9-lin‌​ux‌​-gnueabi/sys-roo‌​t/li‌​b' and 'CFLAGS=-lcrypt' 

from what i understood, LDFLAGS specify the PATH to libraries and CFLAGS will inform the compiler which library to be used. Please do correct me, I am apparently a newbie.

Comment: No. CFLAGS specify the flags used for compiling and LDFLAGS are used as flags for linking.

Comment: @Jakuje Ok, so i corrected it to : 'LDFLAGS='-L/home/cross-gcc-4.9.1-2.19-18-armv7a-soft/x86_64-pc-linux-gn‌​‌​u/arm-cortexa9-lin‌​ux‌​-gnueabi/sys-roo‌​t/li‌​b -lcrypt'' and seems to have worked :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: For Update 4: Hope you can install the header of dependent libraries like glibc zlib etc in target RFS. else you would need to pass as them with CFLAGS & LDFLAGS for headers and libraries.



For Update 6 issue: You could make change in Makefile of openssh for STRIP_OPT as 
STRIP_OPT="--strip-program=arm-linux-gnueabi-strip -s"
This needs to be made in Makefile generate with configure. as configure does not has option to pass strip program or its arguments.

Comment: also update 6 as you are performing cross compile installation. you can use install-nokeys rather than install where it installs with check-config and host-key
check-config tries to run sshd with config
Also host-key as tries to host rsa/dsa key for target target binary which would fail  on host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution was to**

> Add the libcrypt path to the compiler, for some reason the compiler couldnt find the right library

```
LDFLAGS='-L/home/cross-gcc-4.9.1-2.19-18-armv7a-soft/x86_64-pc-linux-gn‌​‌​u/arm-cortexa9-lin‌​ux‌​-gnueabi/sys-roo‌​t/li‌​b -lcrypt'
```

> Added '--disable-strip' to overcome the STRIP error with the install command

**My final configure command looks like this:**

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/Desktop/OpenSSH/OpenSSH_CC --host=arm --disable-strip --with-libs --with-zlib=$HOME/Desktop/Zlib/zlib-1.2.5/output --with-ssl-dir=$HOME/Desktop/OpenSSL/OpenSSL_CC --disable-etc-default-login CC=arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR=arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabi-ar LDFLAGS='-L/home/cross-gcc-4.9.1-2.19-18-armv7a-soft/x86_64-pc-linux-gn‌​‌​u/arm-cortexa9-lin‌​ux‌​-gnueabi/sys-roo‌​t/li‌​b -lcrypt'
make
make install
```

**Thanks to @Jakuje, @Gaurav Pathak and @k_kaz**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `-lcrypt` to `LDFLAGS`, because it is what is passed to the linker (not the `CFLAGS).

Comment: This sure worked, but for some reason i am not able to generate the executables. will update the OP and answer once i am able to close this.


(umask 022 ; ./mkinstalldirs /var/empty)
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh /home/armsdk/Desktop/OpenSSH/OpenSSH_CC/bin/ssh
strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/home/armsdk/Desktop/OpenSSH/OpenSSH_CC/bin/ssh'
/usr/bin/install: strip process terminated abnormally
make: *** [install-files] Error 1

Comment: You probably don't want to run `install` in your system. You install binary looks like it tries to strip the debuginfo or something from the binaries and does not know how to do that.

Comment: how else would i get the executables without the install command ? am i missing something here ?

Comment: Install is usually just a copy from some place to some other. You will find executables in build directory.