# Why does this source code using "crypt" have this compiler warning:

Tags: c, linux, crypt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    const char *key = NULL;
    const char *salt = NULL;
    crypt(key, salt);
    return 0;
}
```

use  *`gcc test.c -o test -Wall -lcrypt`*  to compile.

Which gives this warning:

> initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

Can anyone explain this warning and how to properly avoid it?

Comment: Can you include the line number in the warning message please ?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: no, `crypt()` should be defined in `<unistd.h>`.

Comment: Though I needed to move #define to the first line to make the function declared, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127921/is-the-crypt-function-declared-in-unistd-h-or-crypt-h

Comment: I wonder why your gcc didn't say "implicit declaration of function ‘crypt’", mine did.

Comment: @PaulR The reference page I consulted included crypt.h explicitly instead of specifying _XOPEN_SOURCE. I got "implicit declaration of function ‘crypt’", just like wRAR. (Deleting my comment above, so as to not mislead future readers)

Comment: The line number gets increasingly interesting, because there are no integers at all in your code.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: I think it depends on what flavour of Linux/Unix/whatever that you are using. For anything POSIX or BSD-based (e.g. Mac OS X) then it's `<unistd.h>`, but it may be different on Linux, although [this man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/crypt) suggests it's still `<unistd.h>`.

Comment: On my Linux (RHEL6) it works with `<unistd.h>` if I first define _XOPEN_SOURCE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put feature test macros before *all* includes. In your case, `stdio.h` already includes `features.h` behind the scenes, which takes care of converting the feature defines (like `_XOPEN_SOURCE`) into something internal the headers use. So when you include `unistd.h`, the flags have already been set and won’t be interpreted again, thus, declaring `_XOPEN_SOURCE` in the mean time won’t have any effect.

Changing the order fixes the problem:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    const char *key = NULL;
    const char *salt = NULL;
    crypt(key, salt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *..stdio.h already includes unistd.h behind the scenes.* any reference?

Comment: @KingsIndian You’re correct, it’s including ``features.h``, not ``unistd.h``. I corrected and completed my answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: While I see how this should fix problems with `crypt` prototype, I don't see how any problem with the prototype could cause the warning mentioned in the question. Because the warning says pointer _from_ integer and calling function without prototype can't cause that.

Comment: @JanHudec This is true. I misread that (probably like some others). I’d really like feedback from the asker whether this fixes the problem and if not, where the warning is coming from.

Comment: I guess the warning is coming from `unistd.h` when being compiled in a situation where `stdio.h` had already been compiled with possibly different function definitions

Comment: @MattMcNabb That sounds very plausible.